# ASP.net Web Forms - Dynamic Form - C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, dynamic, webforms

I need to create a form dynamically using a QueryString parameter and access
to all of its fields by ID in code behind.

Now, I have the form (with server controls) but I can't set unique IDs (using things like Eval...)
so I passed from server controls to simple html and now all fields have unique IDs
but I can't access them from code behind (Form.FindControl works only for server controls).

This is my code with html:

```
<%
    int j = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["j"]);

    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
    %>
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="date" id='<%: "date_" + (i + 1).ToString() %>' />
        </div>
    </div>

    <%
    }
    %>
```

If is really impossible to set IDs for server controls (if not, tell me how!)
how can I access those fields? Or how can I create the form using something else
that can helps me?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these controls will be posted back upon form submission and you need to get those values after `postback`, you can access that using `Request.Form["date_0"]`, `Request.Form["date_1"]`, `Request.Form["date_2"]` ....

Comment: Thanks, this works! But like @yogi970 said, I have to add the **name** attribute. I have to use that field for a DB insert, can I do it in the `PageLoad` with `isPostBack` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

just add extra attribute **name** to input type. like

```
 <input type="date" name="myDate"/>
```

now from the server side you can fetch value from form.

```
  string date=  Request.form["mydate"];
```

or

```
 string date=  Request.form[mydate.UniqueID];
```